# Any disadvantage of increasing the partition count in Event hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Few months ago I have created one event hub with default 2 partition count.

Now I am moving to production and just realised that I can't increase partition count.

So any could help me to understand the scenario where I should increase partition count or not ?

Please help me guys

Comment: As Peter Bons mentioned  in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#partitions) that `The number of partitions is specified at creation and must be between 2 and 32. The partition count is not changeable, so you should consider long-term scale when setting partition count`

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to scale out the number of parallel consumers. Each consumer places a lock on the partition they are reading from. Events are evenly distributed over the amount of configured partitions.

So, you will, need to increase the partition count (by recreating the Event Hub) only if you think that now or in the (near) future you won't be able to process the incoming events fast enough.

Summarized: since you have just 2 partitions you can only have 2 consuming processes processing items in parallell (for a given consumer group).

See also the [excellent docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#partitions).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, the trade off is between latency and complexity.

Long answer:

In the following scenario, having less partition number is probably a better choice:

i. You care about the order of events. Within each partition,
 the events are in the ordered sequence. So if you care about event order, having less partitions will help to make the events play in order easier.

ii. If you are using EventProcessorHost has the consuming client, you can't have multiple thread consuming the same partition, in case you want to do that for some reason.
If you are not using EventProcessorHost has the consuming client, then if you don't have a strict latency requirement, managing less partitions will make the code easier, because you need to make sure you have at least one consumer for every partition that is receiving events.